Assign temperature to nodes in Abaqus
Hi I want to select all the nodes that are located at x = 8 mm and assign temperature value of 500 to them. I used so many codes to do that but could not find the solution. I have put part of the code here for your reference.
`    # Access the active model
myModel = mdb.models['Model-1']
# Get the part and its assembly
myPart = myModel.parts['PART-1']
myAssembly = myModel.rootAssembly

# Define the x-coordinate you want to select nodes at
x_coordinate = 8.0

# Select nodes at x=8
nodes_at_x_8 = myPart.nodes.getByBoundingBox(xMin=x_coordinate-0.01, xMax=x_coordinate+0.01)

# Set temperature for selected nodes
for node in nodes_at_x_8:
    myModel.TemperatureBC(name='Temp_' + str(node.label), createStepName='Step-1',region= node,      fixed = False, distributionType=UNIFORM,fieldName='', magnitude=500.0)
# Loop through all the nodes`

Running the above script forced Abaqus to close.

The issue could be with the arguments that you are passing to the getByBoundingBox method.
The getByBoundingBox method takes 6 arguments, xMin, yMin, zMin, xMax, yMax and zMax. These 6 arguments define the bounding box and gives the requested entities within this bounding box (in yoru case, nodes).
You must pass all these 6 arguments regardless of the dimension of your model. 
If your model is 1D, you can pass yMin, zMin, yMax and zMax as zero. 
If your model is 2D, you can pass zMin and zMax as zero.
